# QuerySet in Django

Tags: django, django-models

How can I perform this SQL query

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE column_name != value
```

in the QuerySet of Django?

I tried this but isn't correct way:

[image]

Comment: How is it not correct? `MyModel.objects.filter(field_name=value)` will retrieve all MyModel records where field_name=value

Answer (score 1):

To execute sql queries just use raw method of Model like this:

```
posts = Post.objects.raw("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name != %s;", [value])
for post in posts:
   # do stuff with post object
```

But i don't think you need raw query (unless you want to get rid of ORM overhead to fetch records quicker) you can just use ORM like this:

```
posts = Post.objects.all().exclude(column_name=value)
```

Comment: You can mark this question as accepted if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `Q`:

```
from django.db.models import Q


posts = Post.objects.filter(~Q(column_name=value))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do this query using Django ORM (If I am not wrong). You can do this using **Q** Expression in Django (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/#s-complex-lookups-with-q-objects). For **!=** you can use **~** sign. In your case, the query will look like this

```
Post.objects.filter(~Q(<column_name>=<value>))
```

Another way to use **exclude** method (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#s-exclude)

```
Post.objects.exclude(<column_name>=<value>)
```

Both queries generate the same raw query in your case:

```
SELECT * FROM <table_name> WHERE NOT (<column_name>=<value)
```

If you want to do the raw query then you can use **raw** method (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/sql/)

```
posts = Post.objects.raw("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name != %s;", [value])
```

If you want to execute a custom raw query directly then use **cursor** **from django.db connection** (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/sql#s-executing-custom-sql-directly)